# Working With Classes & Placing Frame inside The Window But Giving Error

Tags: user-interface, exception, tkinter, widget, frame

being a starter I am facing this difficulty.

> TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

I want to work with classes and thus making frame in window, and unable tracing error .What does this error mean? please suggest me some easy tutorial site or youtube lecture on completely covering the topics with classes. One guess i made was to pack it again maybe inside the root(window). So I took chance to make it this way, butttt.

```
from tkinter import \*
from tkinter import ttk

class kk(Tk):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.geometry("600x200")

class MainFrame(ttk):
def __init__(self, container):
super().__init__(container)

    self.l1=ttk.Label(self, text= "Bill No.", font=("digital 7",12,"bold", "italic"))
    self.l1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e1var=StringVar()
    self.e1=ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.e1var,width=30,border=4, font=("digital 7",12,"bold", "italic"))
    self.e1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    self.l1=ttk.Label(self, text= "DESCRIPTION", font=("digital 7",12,"bold", "italic"))
    self.l1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    self.e1var=StringVar()
    self.e1=ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.e1var,width=30,border=4, font=("digital 7",12,"bold", "italic"))
    self.e1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    self.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    if __name__=="__main__":
    window=kk()
    frame1=MainFrame(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please set the indentation probably.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `MainFrame` is trying to inherit from a module, which is why the error mentions `module`. The way you've written the code, it appears you intended to inherit from `ttk.Frame`.

```
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
```